# When hover header change opacity image

Tags: javascript, css, hover, opacity

I need the image to change opacity also when hover the header.
Now I have the opacity only when hover the image.

See example fiddle script here:
http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/EmsaG/1/

## JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $("img.a").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
    },
    function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
  }); 
});
```

## HTML:

```
<div class="m-blok one">
    <h3 class="m-kop"><a href="#">Some header</a></h3>
    <img class="a" src="http://tinyurl.com/732qwvt" width="178" height="78" alt="" style="opacity: 1;">
    <img class="b" src="http://tinyurl.com/nrbj2uk" width="178" height="78" alt="" />
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.m-blok{width:178px; height:78px; position:relative; margin:15px;}

img.a {left: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: 10;}
img.b {left: 0; position: absolute; top: 0;}

.m-kop{position:absolute; z-index:11; color:#fff; margin:55px 0 0 5px; max-width:150px; background:#f00;}
.m-kop a, .m-kop a:hover{color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what you already done, you can do it like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $("img.a, .m-kop").hover(
    function() {
      $("img.a").stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
    },
    function() {
      $("img.a").stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed! I have made a little change in the fiddle.
I need the header to have opacity 0 on hover and added some other divs. But now they all change on hover. See: http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/EmsaG/4/   You know how to fix this?

Comment: By the way, you have a block with 3 times the same <a href>. You should put everythin (<h1> and  <img>'s) inside a global <a>

Comment: THANKS EdenSource, it works now, I needed to remove the header when hover too but this is fixed now :D http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/EmsaG/7/  (and for the a href tip!)